# VBA invalid qualifier error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Not sure why I get an invalid qualifier error? Just looking in a range of numbers for least neg value and select (note ea number in ea of the cells is the result of a formula)

```
Sub Test()
    Dim c As Double
    c = .Find(What:=ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=LARGE(V17:V57,COUNTIF(V17:V57,"">0"")+1)"), LookIn:=xlValues)
            If c <> 0 Then
            c.Select
            End If
 End Sub
```

Based on comments so far the code is now as follows

```
Sub Test()
Dim c As Variant, a As Variant
    c = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("LARGE(V17:V57,COUNTIF(V17:V57,"">0"")+1)")
    Debug.Print c
    a = Application.Match(-0.199999999999818, "V17:V57", 0)
    'a = Application.Match(c, ActiveSheet.Range("V17:V57"))
    If IsError(a) Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("V17:V57").Cells(a, 1).Address
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA "Invalid Qualifier Error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944210/vba-invalid-qualifier-error)

Answer (score 1):

[`.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) is a method of Range object.

You need to pass a range object.

General format would be:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("V17:V57").Find(What:="letter", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        c.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that `c` is a range object which is what is returned by `.Find` method. The example search range in `ActiveSheet.Range("V17:V57")`.

You test whether a value was found with the `Is Nothing`, as if the value wasn't found the range object c will be set to nothing.

You need to handle a possible error value from `=LARGE(V17:V57,COUNTIF(V17:V57,">0")+1)`  if that is what the `Evaluate` formula produces otherwise you will get an error.

For example:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim c As Range, a As Variant
    a = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("LARGE(V17:V57,COUNTIF(V17:V57,"">0"")+1)")
    If IsError(a) Then Exit Sub
    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("V17:V57").Find(What:= a, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        c.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Make sure to format your column to shown the decimal places so that Find can match accurately.

See discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966772/vba-range-find-function-on-rounded-negative-numbers).

---

If you cannot format the sheet to show the require decimals try using Match. Sorry that I have c and a differently below.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim c As Variant, a As Variant
    c = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("LARGE(V17:V57,COUNTIF(V17:V57,"">0"")+1)")
    a = Application.Match(c, ActiveSheet.Range("V17:V57"))
    If IsError(a) Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("V17:V57").Cells(a, 1).Address
End Sub
```

Comment: New to VBA. Any suggestions...you mean for eg adding .ActiveSheet to end of Find line?  That didn't work

Comment: Tried it and get run time error 91...Object variable or With block variable not set. My variable is now define as such `c = ActiveSheet.Range("V17:V57").Find(What:=ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=LARGE(V17:V57,COUNTIF(V17:V57,"">0"")+1)"), LookIn:=xlValues)`

Comment: OK now I get no error with your last suggested code but nothing is happening. I can see the smallest neg value is -0.2 in this range but the cell is not being selected with this code. Blank result. The formula in ea of the cells by the way is like this `=$V$17-T29`, for eg

Comment: Good question! It gives `-0.199999999999818 `

Comment: I think the problem with .Find is that .Find does not search the cell value, but the cell string. An alternative may be to step through each cell checking the actual value but I'm not sure how to modify your code accordingly. Just a thought

Comment: Debug.print c.Address under the Set c = ... line gives a debug error but when placed under the c.Select it results in nothing. Blank. BUT if I expand manually the number of digits displayed in the cell with least neg value (-0.2) to exactly the same as what the number seen from the Debug.Print a (-0.199999999999818) then the code you proposed works

Comment: Your code had a as a Variant. I change a to Double and no difference

Comment: The line `If Not c Is Nothing Then: Debug.Print c.Address` gives blank in intermediate window

Comment: Previously I was trying to explain when the value in the cell is showing -0.2, the macro does nothing after it's run. But expanding the number of decimal places manually until the least min value cell displays -0.199999999999818 the macro works

Comment: Yes it is certainly is the range but only seen like that when I manually expand it. Normally that same cell is showing -0.2. So the macro is not able at present to deal with the floating decimal point situation. I believe this is an inherent problem with .Find (it works on strings and not values)

Comment: No I can't display my results in this range with that many decimals. Somehow the code needs interpret the value. I'm tending to think now the .Find needs to be replaced...

Comment: I saw the link you posted . Thanks. That approach looks a bit tricky for me. Can you please advise more on the match

Comment: I have added an example in at the bottom as an edit.

Comment: Please note that the numbers in these cells within this range will change depending on some user action in some other part of this worksheet. The user changes a value in this other location and the values in the range are updated. Then the user needs to run this macro, each time the other location cell value is changed

Comment: Then you update the code accordingly. I am just showing you how it might look. So you would replace the hard coded value with the evaluate “”

Comment: OK starting to get it but first I ask please why you class the variables as Variants? Why not Double?

Comment: Because both your evaluate and Match could potentially return an error. A variant can hold this error without throwing a type mismatch. If it is double all well as will be variant/double. You can then test for whether is an error and use that to determine what to do next.

Comment: That latest code modification with Match doesn't produce a result. Nothing happens when run. The immediate window shows $V$57

Comment: V57 is the last cell in the range, holds a number but is not the least negative

Comment: No. Debug.Print c gives the -0.19999999...value

Comment: The value is -0.199999999999818 and not found in V57. The only change I made to the code was to the line `a = Application.Match(-0.199999999999818, "V17:V57", 0)` and the immediate window gives -0.199999999999818 , $V$57. The code does nothing in the worksheet. Still nothing happening in the worksheet when ran

Comment: What is the value of Match(-0.199999999999818,V17:V57,0)  when you put that formula in the sheet?

Comment: I have added the latest code I am using at the bottom of my original question as an edit. The V17:V57 needs the `" "` else I get a compile error. How do you wnat me to change it to do what you just asked?

Comment: I am asking you to put Match(-0.199999999999818,V17:V57,0)  in the worksheet. Not in the code. Put it in the sheet where the value is found. And tell me what value it returns please. :-)

Comment: Sorry. The least neg value of -0.199999999999818 is in cell V27. I replaced that cell with `=MATCH(-0.199999999999818,V17:V57,0)` and I get first a warning that there's a circular reference, then I click OK and get the value 0

Comment: No. Don't put the formula in the range. Put it in an empty cell no in the range. You are just checking what the expected value is.

Comment: It now gives #N/A. I tried Ctrl / Shft / Enter and still #N/A

Comment: That would mean the value is not found in the range

Comment: The Match works perfecly if I replace (in the standalone Match formula) the raw number with the formula in the cell that generates that number, no matter how many decimal points are used to display the number in that cell, but not directly with the number itself.

Comment: It works if you use the formula or the hardcoded value with the decimal places? Do you have a workbook you can send?

Comment: Using the Match formula in the worksheet, in a standalone cell, works. This formula in the worksheet works perfectly `=MATCH($V$17-T27,V17:V57,0)`, no matter how many decimal places the cell is formatted to, but this formula `=MATCH(-0.199999999999818,V17:V57,0)` gives an #N/A

Comment: The focus now is to understand why your code does not recognise the raw number in the cell, no matter how many decimal places are shown. My workbook by the way is not publically available but I may be able to send you a heavily edited version but that will take some time

Comment: Is $V$17-T27 = -0.199999999999818 ? Or is there rounding? At 16 digits I think there is rounding. In which case you need to match on a rounded figure.

Comment: Yes exactly. The least neg value in my range, for the given scenario being assessed, is -0.199999999999818 and it is in a cell which has the formula $V$17-T27. So obvioulsy that formula determines the value -0.199999999999818 BUT normally that cell, in this example, shows only -0.2 and I cannot really allow the cells in this particular range to show any more decimal places

Comment: Note that if I continue to manually show more decimal places in this particular cell, with this particular result, the extra digits are all 0. For eg -0.19999999999981800000000000. Hence the full precision of this particilaur cell is reached with the number -0.199999999999818

Comment: Can you round to 1dp and match on that? Seems inaccurate IMO.

Comment: Maybe @jeeped can come to the rescue?

Comment: Sorry not clear what you ask. But for eg if I leave the cell in question displaying -0.2, and use the Match formula in the worksheet as follows `=MATCH(-0.2,V17:V57,0)` I get a #N/A

Comment: I don't know @jeeped  but yes this ones a tough one

Answer (score 0):

To use the entire sheet used range try this.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim c As Double
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set c = .Find(What:=ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=LARGE(V17:V57,COUNTIF(V17:V57,"">0"")+1)"), LookIn:=xlValues)
            If c <> 0 Then
            c.Select
            End If
    End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: I just want to look in the range `V17:V57`. Not entire sheet

Comment: Instead `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` use `ActiveSheet.Range("V17:V57")`.

Comment: that still gives me a quailifier error. Only change I made to your code was `With ActiveSheet.Range("V17:V57")`